Blazor App on IIS does not work on recent IOS
I need some guidance  in troubleshooting an issue where a website hosted on a local IIS Server fails to load correctly on newer iPhone models (specifically, iPhone 12 Pro) using Chrome and Safari browsers. The website initially displays a blank page for a few seconds before showing an error message (as depicted in the image provided). This issue does not occur with older iPhones or on any other devices (computers, Android phones) which can access the site normally across various browsers.This phone have access to any other sites I assuming some DNS problems ...
The server logs do not reveal any errors, and websockets are functioning correctly. Our application is developed using .NET 8.0 and hosted with the ASP.NET Core Runtime 8.0.10 bundle in IIS. My Visual Studio is up to date with version 17.11.5.
As I have minimal experience with iPhones and limited familiarity with Blazor, I'm looking for initial steps or strategies to begin diagnosing this problem. I will soon have access to an iPhone from my IT department to conduct tests, but any preliminary guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated for troubleshooting. All devices are connected to the same WiFi network.
edited: The reason of this behaviour and how I fixed is in my last comment.


Are you testing on an actual device or a simulated device using a PC browser?

No simulated, actual devices issues only with newer Iphones. Since I am using my colleagues phones I try not to be intrusive until I get one. Hopes give me same error to be able to trace the problem.

For the server part, please use IIS "Failed Request Tracing Module". While defining the tracing rule, on "Define Trace Conditions" page only "Time Taken(sec)" field should be entered with enough time to generate the condition that you are experiencing. The module will log the requests lasting for x sec or more. You may for ex. enter 5 sec if you get the above error after 5 or more seconds. Then regenerate the error to fill up trace logs on the disk.
By default C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles is the directory fills up with log files, one file per each request that the rule captures. You may find the more information about reading trace logs at:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/reading-a-freb-log-a-failed-request-tracing-iis-request/ba-p/1349639
In the trace logs, you may find the module on the IIS server which makes the application wait.
From the client side another useful tool will be curl tool or invoke-webrequest (powershell) cmdlet. They are similar tools that you can send a web request with a user agent such as Chrome, FireFox, Internet Explorer, Opera, and Safari or for curl  curl -A "Agent 007" https://example.com (Ref: curl.se man page) As user agent you may input your application's related header information. With the trace option of the curl tool you can get detailed information about packets sent / received.
I suspect something related to TLS versions for example newer IOS will send TLS 1.3 requests which the server does not accept. In the curl trace you may find these details, this will show you whether the request is broken at the beginning during the TLS handshake.

It gives me the same error when using http or https. For instance is am using self signed key for development purposes; I will try, when I get back to follow your recomandations.

I had set up the trace as you described. No trace, no log also from these IOS clients nothing. I suspect the DNS on these phones. It's like the phone does not know about wifi internal network. I still wait a phone from my IT to test.
Other clients desktop browsers, android clients leave at least a log on IIS. Truncated to avoid the max
2024-10-28 15:24:51 POST /_blazor/negotiate negotiateVersion=1 443 - 10.1.2.147 HTTP/2 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:131.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/131.0 - https:// ...
2024-10-28 15:24:51 W3SVC2  10.1.1.10 GET /_framework/blazor.server.js -

As I understand from the logs, the application uses HTTP/2  - TLS (Port:443).  Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis#when-is-http2-not-supported . Windows Authentication is not supported and cause fallback to HTTP 1.1 . Moreover I highly recommend to test IIS vDir or APP SSL settings with 'Client Certificates Ignored' setting. Newer IOS may have client certs built-in.

You pointed me on the right direction. I enabled SSL > IGNORE SAVE and remove after and SAVE again. Now the site is accessible from those phones also. I do not understand the behind off it. It works now. Thank you so much I am days after this behaviour. Still I have to find more info to document it clearly for my team.

I am glad that it is solved. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-http2-secondary-certs-04 may help on technical details of http2 and client certificate interactions.

The reason was with SSL enabled some phones had some keys loaded into pointing to something else (like watchguard) in our LAN. By setting ignore SSL on that site fixed the issue.
